# get first five values from json and then get remaining values too

Tags: jquery

I have a `json` data and I want to get first 5 items from this and after that get remaining data.

for getting first five data.I am doing following way and it is getting properly.
Here report is the `json` data

```
 var recentreport =  report.slice(0, 5)
```

`recentreport` `prints first five values in the json`

after getting first five data jsoncontains remaining 10 more values 
how can I get the remaining data too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the same [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var remaining = report.slice(5)
```